# Docker RabbitMQ persistency

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, containers, dockerfile

RabbitMQ in docker lost data after remove container without volume.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
ENV RABBITMQ_HIPE_COMPILE 1
ENV RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE "123456"
ENV RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST "123456"
```

My run script:

```sh
IMAGE_NAME="service-rabbitmq"
TAG="${REGISTRY_ADDRESS}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${VERSION}"

echo $TAG

docker rm -f $IMAGE_NAME

  docker run \
    -itd \
    -v "rabbitmq_log:/var/log/rabbitmq" \
    -v "rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq" \
    --name "service-rabbitmq" \
    --dns=8.8.8.8 \
    -p 8080:15672 \
    $TAG
```

After removing the container, all data are lost.

How do I configure RabbitMQ in docker with persistent data?

Comment: I tried asking a similar question here but got no good answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897360/export-rabbitmq-docker-image-with-vhost-and-queues

Comment: A related issue is here on the rabbitmq docker github home https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/106

Comment: Any update on nowadays?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> Rabbitmq uses the hostname as part of the folder name in the mnesia
> directory. Maybe add a `--hostname some-rabbit` to your docker run?

I had the same issue and I found the answer [here](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/106#issuecomment-241882358).

Comment: Yeah. To clarify the mnesia folder, we can calling `docker logs $YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME` to see the line `database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@$YOUR_HOST_NAME` ref. https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/

Comment: You could also set the `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` environment variable to something like `node@rabbitmq` instead of changing the hostname

Comment: Following this URL I solved with: docker run -d -v /MY_LOCAL/Data/Rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq --hostname my-rabbit --name rabbit-dev -p 8080:15672 -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management

Answer (score 45):

### TL;DR

Didn't do *too* much digging on this, but it appears that the simplest way to do this is to change the `hostname` as Pedro mentions above.

### MORE INFO:

#### Using `RABBITMQ_NODENAME`

If you want to edit the `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` variable via Docker, it looks like you need to add a `hostname` as well since the Docker hostnames are generated as random hashes.

If you change the `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` var to something static like `my-rabbit`, RabbitMQ will throw something like an `"nxdomain not found"` error because it's looking for something like
`my-rabbit@<docker_hostname_hash>`. <s>If you know the Docker hostname and can automate pulling it into your `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` value like so, `my-rabbit@<docker_hostname_hash>` I believe it would work.</s>

---

**UPDATE**

I previously said,

> If you know the Docker hostname and can automate pulling it into your `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` value like so, `my-rabbit@<docker_hostname_hash>` I believe it would work.

This would not work as described precisely because the default docker host name is randomly generated at launch, if it is not assigned explicitly. The hurdle would actually be to make sure you use the EXACT SAME `<docker_hostname_hash>` as your originating run so that the data directory gets picked up correctly. This would be a pain to implement dynamically/robustly. It would be easiest to use an explicit hostname as described below.

---

The alternative would be to set the `hostname` to a value you choose -- say, `app-messaging` -- **AND ALSO** set the `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` var to something like `rabbit@app-messaging`. This way you are controlling the full node name that will be used in the data directory.

#### Using Hostname

(*Recommended*)

That said, unless you have a reason **NOT** to change the hostname, changing the hostname alone is the simplest way to ensure that your data will be mounted to and from the same point every time.

I'm using the following Docker Compose file to successfully persist my setup between launches.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    hostname: 'mabbit'
    image: "${ARTIFACTORY}/rabbitmq:3-management"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/"
    networks:
      - rabbitmq

networks:
  rabbitmq:
    driver: bridge
```

This creates a `data` directory next to my compose file and persists the RabbitMQ setup like so:

```sh
./data/
  rabbit@mabbit/
  rabbit@mabbit-plugins-expand/
  rabbit@mabbit.pid
  rabbit@mabbit-feature_flags
```